# What pattern should I use to create Objects that are functions of other Objects?

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

I have a collection of instances of a class called `LogicSignal`

I have a set of methods and "operator" methods I can call on these instances, for example

```
anded = signal_a & signal_b.value_at_cycle_n_minus(2)
```

will give me the bitwise and of the value of signal_a at the current time and the value of signal_b at the current cycle - 2.

The signals change with time, so when I run this

```
puts signal_a & signal_b  
advance_time
puts signal_a & signal_b
```

I will get the values anded at different times

But if I run this

```
anded = signal_a & signal_b
puts added
advance_time
puts anded
```

I will get the same values printed.

**The problem is that I need to pass arbitrary functions of signals into other objects, and they need to be able to get the results of those functions at arbitrary times.**

I know that if run this

```
anded = lambda { signal_a & signal_b }
puts anded.call
advance_time
puts anded.call
```

I will get the values anded at different times, but `anded` is not a signal, so I can't use it in place of a signal.
So for example if some object needed to be able to get the `anded` value at some arbitrary point in time, it could not call anded.value_at_cycle_n_minus() , because `anded` is a proc and not a signal

My first thought is to use something like the composite pattern and create a CompositeLogicSignal class that implents all the methods of the LogicSignal class but does so by calling a proc that takes the child signals.

So I would have something like this

```
anded = CompositeLogicSignal.new [signal_a, signal_b] , lambda { |a,b| a & b }
```

Is there an easier way, or is there some other pattern that makes more sense for this problem?

Comment: Does [`Proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html) helpful ? :)

Comment: why not make `&` return CompositeLogicSignal instead of LogicSignal?

Comment: I thought you are looking for _anonymous objects_ ... That's why gave the link..

Comment: @iced I don't actually have a CompositeLogicSignal class as of right now,  & currently returns the anded value at that moment.

Comment: make Composite class as you self-suggested and just return it. It'll look like normal Logic class to the rest of the code and will get the job done.

Comment: There might be a better idiomatic way of doing this in ruby, but if `LogicSignal` had a method such as `bitAnd` that was returning a `BitAndCompositeLogicSignal` it seems like you could easily compose things. Basically, `anded = signal_a.bitAnd(signal_b)` ...